# excel VBA trying to get my macro to run faster

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get my macro to run a bit faster and i was wondering which way is the fastest:

1)

```
Set cell2 = Range("F" & CurrentRow)
Set Columns = Range(cell2, cell2.Offset(0, LastColumn - 6))
i = 0
For Each cell In Columns
If cell.Value = " - " Then
Else
    ...code...
Next cell
```

2)

```
Set cell2 = Range("F" & CurrentRow)
CurrentColumn=6
While CurrentColumn <= LastColumn
     Cells(CurrentColumn,CurrentRow).Value...code...
     CurrentColumn = CurrentColumn+1
Wend
```

And is there a faster way than these two?

Thanks in advance,
Bruno

Comment: What happens when you try them? Is one faster than the other? Also, it's hard to say what a faster way might be, because you didn't tell us what your `...code...` does, or even describe the problem you're trying to solve. "Is this faster than this?" usually can't be decided without actually testing the two alternatives using *your data*, which of course we don't have available.

Comment: my code only takes the values in the cells and adds them to a variable, the problem is when i have a lot of rows and columns, i tries testing both before but the data i ahd wasnt too much to tell a difference, i'll try to get more data to test both of them, is there a way to get how long it took to run so i can compare both performances?

Comment: If you don't have enough data to tell the difference, you don't need to worry about which one is faster yet. :-) You don't need to worry about "making things faster" until you have something that is slow.

Comment: right now i don't have because i'm developing it at home, but i took it once to work and i took a long time, that's why i'm trying to make it faster :) i already found how to time the executions. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726673(v=office.14).aspx#xlFasterVBA

Comment: I doubt you'll get to a situation where there are enough rows to make a meaningful difference unless you are making calculations with formulas on several columns millions of rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to loop through a range is to dump it into a variant and loop through that. Each call to Excel from VBA will be expensive (only noticable with large data though) and looping through a variant is blazing fast.

Sample code

```
Sub test()

Dim data As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

'Example range
data = Range("A1:Z100").Value

For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
    For j = LBound(data, 2) To UBound(data, 2)
        If data(i, j) = " - " Then
            'Do something
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do to speed up VBA code that updates the values in a lot of cells is to add the following line before your code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Then your code; and finally

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

You will be astonished how much faster your code will run. Plus the screen won't be flickering while the macro runs.